# Provider information in azure to run command for azure portal?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I am unable to find information regarding azure provider information in ARM or using azure CLI?

I looked in the portal and google but none are providing the information?

I need the provider information so I can connect to Azure and run `terraform` deployment via azure `terraform`.

I want to place in a tf file. Can I separate the below into a single tf file and place other resources, such as the actual deployment of `vnet`, `subnets`, `Iaas deployment`, `public IP`, etc. all in separate tf files?

```
provider "azurerm" {
   subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   client_secret   = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
   name     = "myResourceGroup"
   location = "eastus"
   tags = {
      environment = "Terraform Demo"
   }
}
```

I am trying to find the `client_id` and `client_secret`

Is `id` the same as `subscription_id`?

What is `isDefault = True`?  What is the difference form is `Default = False`?

Can I assume the False is the free trial then the True is the actual pay as you go?

output appeared automatically when logged in from azure CLI:

```
[
  {
     "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
     "id": "21eb90c5-a6ed-4819-a2d0-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "isDefault": true,
     "name": "Pay-As-You-Go",
     "state": "Enabled",
     "tenantId": "1d6cd91f-d633-4291-8eca-XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "user": {
       "name": "samename01@yahoo.com",
       "type": "user"
     }
  },
  {
     "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
     "id": "b6d5b1ee-7327-42a0-b8e3-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "isDefault": false,
     "name": "Pay-As-You-Go",
     "state": "Enabled",
     "tenantId": "1d6cd91f-d633-4291-8eca-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "user": {
       "name": "samename01@yahoo.com",
       "type": "user"
     }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I separate the below into a single tf file and place other resources such as the actual deployment of vnet, subnets, Iaas deployment, public IP,... all in separate tf files?

Yes, you can separate Terraform configuration out into as many files as you'd like, as long as those files are in the same directory. So in your case it sounds like you might want a file for each resource (providers.tf, vnet.tf, subnet.tf, etc.)

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX I am trying to find the "client_id" and "client_secret"? Is "id" the same as subscription_id? What is isDefault = True? What is the difference form is Default = False? Can I assume the False is the free trial then the True is the actual pay as you go?

This has nothing to do with billing and payments, you can just ignore the `isDefault` flag since it's not important. What is important is the **subscription id**, a basic Terraform configuration will authenticate against **1 Azure subscription**, and billing/payments in Azure are at the subscription level.

`client_id` is the **application id** of  your service principal which you will use to authenticate Terraform in Azure. [This is the instructions for setting that up](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/service_principal_client_secret.html), it's fairly simple.